# Add multiple kits to Drum Rack?

Tags: ableton-live, ableton

How can I add multiple drum kits to a rack? It looks like I could just drag/drop over a section of the "keys", but it keeps dropping over the "default" C Scale...How can I drop multiple on the same rack?

[image]

Edit: As mentioned in a comment under an answer below, the general idea is to have multiple kits available so as I go up/down the keyboard, I can trigger various drums...see [this mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfipU.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than manually adding pads in at the correct pitches I have found that you can Group 2 drum racks into an Instrument rack, and use a midi pitch effect set to -16 or +16 etc. I think this may do it for you!When you drop that adg file it is overwriting the other kit in that space. You could chain racks together to get them on the same track or manually move samples from one rack to the other, or I'd just have separate racks and put them in a group as below, that way you can control the racks' volumes individually and sum them together on a group channel. [How to Group tracks in Ableton](https://obedia.com/creating-track-groups-in-ableton-live/)

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on how to group separate racks together? That sounds promising

Comment: @BruceWayne updated answer ;)

Comment: @BruceWayne One thing you did not mention is WHY you want to do this ;)

Comment: Perhaps it's an XY Problem - but the basic idea is that I have a midi keyboard with 3 octaves.  Instead of just having an 808 kit from "Middle C" to the next "C", if I keep going up an octave, would like to trigger another Kit...does [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfipU.jpg) help visualize what I mean? [Ignore the fact that an 808 kit/Conga Kit/etc may have more/less keys used, just the general idea should hopefully be clear :)  ]

Comment: @BruceWayne other than manually I found that you can Group 2 drum racks into an  Instrument rack, and use a midi pitch effect set to -16 or +16 etc. I think this may do it for you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay - that seems to do it! Although it could cause for a rather busy Group/set, it looks like this is the easier way (grouping)...unless I wanted to manually move around tons of individual sounds which...nah.  Thanks!